# ColdFusion Error Roadblock

Tags: coldfusion

I am VERY new to this, so please excuse the possible ignorance of this question:

I have a client that is getting a ColdFusion error "An error occurred while executing the application"
I looked in the log file and found the following error:

ENGINEERR is undefined in SESSION. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PressSchedule_update\salesQuoteEditItemDetails.cfm, line: 53

When I look in the code at line 53, this is what I have:

//var loc = 'insertmessagemain.cfm?engineer='+ '#session.engineer#' + '&type=' + messagetype;

Can anyone point me in the direction of where to look to see where I can define ENGINEER?

Comment: on `session` of course. you'll have to figure out what within the app is defining `engineer` on `session`, then figure out in what situations it can become unset, or not initially set.

Comment: It might be relevent to note that you have a spelling mismatch on the word engineer.

Answer (score 0):

To know where session.engineer is defined, follow the steps in your application in the same way the client would. The most likely location is the page visited just before salesQuoteEditItemDetails.cfm.

Your use of the keyword 'var' suggests we're in the context of a function. So, another place to look is the last page from which the function is called.

In any case, you could avoid the error by setting a default value for session.engineer, as follows:

```
if (NOT structKeyExists(session,'engineer')) {
    session.engineer = "your_default_engineer_value";
}

var loc = 'insertmessagemain.cfm?engineer=' & session.engineer & '&type=' & messagetype;
```